# A puzzle of thermalization in simulating the 3D XY-model

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, computational-physics, phase-transition, spin-models

I am learning the classical Monte Carlo simulation. When I simulate the 3D XY-model 
$$
\beta H = -\beta J \sum_{<i,j>} cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)
$$
where $\beta$ is the inverse of the temperature and $J$ is the coupling constant.

I am using the Metropolis algorithm in C++. I find deep in the order phase, e.g, $\beta J = 1.6$ (the critical value for the 3D XY-Model is $0.44$), the free energy can be "thermalized" very fast. However, after the free energy is "thermalized", the magnetization can still dramatically fluctuate. And we I run the code again (for several times) I got the same free energy but different magnetization.

Following are the plots of the free energy and the magnetization for a $12 \times 12 \times 12$ lattice (thermalized by 10,000 steps) and also my code which can give the resonable critical point but have problem deep in the order phase.

The first plot is the thermalization process of the free energy which seems given the information that the system is thermalized within several Monte Carlo steps. The second and the third plots are the thermalization process of the magnetization. They are run by the same parameter but give quite different results.

I am very appreciate for any hits.

[image: Thermalization process of the free energy]
[image: Thermalization process of the magnetization] 
[image: Thermalization process of the magnetization( run the code again)]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h> 

using namespace std; 


const int Lx = 12;
const int Ly = Lx;
const int Lz = Lx;

int N_site = Lx*Ly*Lz;


double J_min = 1.6;
double J_max = J_min + 0.03;
double J_step = 0.2;

double J; 


// discretization

int N_theta = 10;

int n_theta;

const double pi = 3.1415926;


int MC_step = 5000;
int thermal_steps = 10000;


double theta[Lx][Ly][Lz];

int x_P, x_N, y_P, y_N, z_P, z_N;

double m_avr = 0;
double S_avr = 0; 

double ratio;


void random_n() 
{

  n_theta = int(N_theta * drand48());

  }

void initialize() // fields are global variables, so here don't need parameters
{
  int x, y, z;

  for(z = 0; z < Lz; z++)
    { for(y = 0; y < Ly; y++)
      { for(x = 0; x < Lx; x++)
        {
          random_n();

          theta[x][y][z] = 2*pi / N_theta *n_theta;

          }


        }

      }
  }

void find_neighbours(int x, int y, int z)
{
  x_P = x == 0 ? Lx - 1 : x - 1;
  x_N = x == Lx - 1 ? 0 : x + 1;

  y_P = y == 0 ? Ly - 1 : y - 1;
  y_N = y == Ly - 1 ? 0 : y + 1;

  z_P = z == 0 ? Lz - 1 : z - 1;
  z_N = z == Lz - 1 ? 0 : z + 1;

  }


double S_site(int x, int y, int z) // energy every site
{
  double s;

  find_neighbours(x, y, z); //gives value to x_P, x_N, ...


  s = -J*(cos(theta[x][y][z] - theta[x_P][y][z])
    + cos(theta[x_N][y][z] - theta[x][y][z])
    + cos(theta[x][y][z] - theta[x][y_P][z])
    + cos(theta[x][y_N][z] - theta[x][y][z])
    + cos(theta[x][y][z] - theta[x][y][z_P])
    + cos(theta[x][y][z_N] - theta[x][y][z]));


  return s;

  }


bool flip()
{
  int x, y, z;
  double save_theta; 

  double s, s_save;

  double flip_ratio;


  x = int(Lx* drand48()); // choose random site
  y = int(Ly* drand48());
  z = int(Lz* drand48());


  s_save = S_site(x, y, z);


  save_theta = theta[x][y][z];



  random_n(); // re-initialize the four n; use to change theta and phi;

  theta[x][y][z] += 2*pi/ N_theta *n_theta;

  s = S_site(x, y, z); // energy after flip

  double delta_S = s - s_save;

  if(delta_S < 0)
    {return true;}
  else{
    flip_ratio = exp(-delta_S);


    if (flip_ratio > drand48())
      {return true;}
    else {
       theta[x][y][z] = save_theta;       
       return false;
        }
    }
  }


void oneMCstep()
{
  int i;
  double accept = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < N_site; i++)
    {
      flip();

      if(flip()) {accept++;}
      }

  ratio = accept/N_site;

  }



double magnetization_cos()
{
  int x, y, z;
  double m_cos = 0;

  for(z = 0; z < Lz; z++)
    { for(y = 0; y < Ly; y++)
      { for(x = 0; x < Lx; x++)  // sweep lattice fine
        {
          m_cos += cos(theta[x][y][z]);

          }
        }

      }  
  return m_cos/ N_site;

  }


double S_total()
{
  int x, y, z;
  double S = 0;
  double s;

    for(z = 0; z < Lz; z++)

    { for(y = 0; y < Ly; y++)
      { for(x = 0; x < Lx; x++)
        {
          s = S_site(x, y ,z);
          S += s;
          }


        }

      }

  S /= 2; 

  return S;

  }



void thermalization()
{
  int i;
  double m;
  double S;

  ofstream file_m, file_S;

  file_m.open("cooling_XY_m_thermal.data");
  file_S.open("cooling_XY_S_thermal.data");

  for(i = 0; i < thermal_steps; i++)
  {

    m = magnetization_cos();
    S = S_total();

    file_m << i << '\t' << m << endl;
    file_S << i << '\t' << S << endl;

    oneMCstep();

    }

  file_m.close();
  file_S.close();

  }


void runMC()
{
  int i;
  double m;
  double S;

  ofstream file_m, file_S;

  file_m.open("m.data");
  file_S.open("S.data");

  for(i = 0; i < MC_step; i++)
  {

    m = magnetization_cos();

    S = S_total();

    m_avr += m;
    S_avr += S;

    file_m << i << '\t' << m << endl;
    file_S << i << '\t' << S << endl;

    oneMCstep();

    }

  m_avr /= MC_step;
  m_avr = fabs(m_avr);

  S_avr /= MC_step;  
  file_m.close();
  file_S.close();

  }  

int main()
{  
  srand48(time(0));

  initialize();

  ofstream file_m, file_S;
  ofstream file_ratio;

  file_m.open("cooling_XY_m.data");
  file_S.open("cooling_XY_S.data");
  file_ratio.open("cooling_XY_ratio.data");  

  for(J = J_min; J <= J_max; J += J_step)
  {
  thermalization();

  runMC();

  file_m << J << '\t' << m_avr << endl;
  file_S << J << '\t' << S_avr/J << endl;
  file_ratio << J << '\t' << ratio << endl;
  }

  file_m.close();
  file_S.close();  
  file_ratio.close();

  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure debugging code falls within the scope of this site. In fact it's generally not a good omen for conceptual understanding if you feel compelled to even mention what language your code is written in.

Comment: Magnetic susceptibility is basically the variance of magnetization. Is there any reason for you to expect that this goes to 0? If it not then you should see magnetization fluctuating around some average value.

Comment: @Bubble But the magnetization fluctuate too dramatical, which seems to me not even thermalized.

Comment: @hongchaniyi, calculate $\chi$ and see whether it makes sense or not. What kind of $\chi$ do you expect here. It looks like it's fluctuating around some mean to me. Obviously, $\chi$ should decrease away from the phase transition (with lower or higher temperatures).

Comment: @Bubble The description to the plots doesn't showing well. The problem is if I just re-run the code without changing any parameters, the thermalization process of the free energy almost same, but the thermalization process of the magnetization are quite different. In fact, I am not sure whether the system is not thermalized well.

Comment: @hongchaniyi What do you mean by quite different? Try plotting $\chi$ vs. temperature and see whether it behaves as expected. How do you know that the fluctuations are "too big"?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd buy your results, given the extreme differences in values (the first drops to -7500, the second to -0.9 and the third to +0.3). That suggests to me that something is fundamentally wrong with your code, which, as ChrisWhite points out, debugging code is off-topic at this site; it *could* be on topic at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @KyleKanos I think they're not plots of the same thing.

Comment: @Bubble: Ah, yes. The first image *is* different from the latter two (which are the same), but even with those large differences in results, I still suspect the code is the issue.

Comment: @KyleKanos I honestly have no idea, but I would first make some checks to see whether I can reproduce some known behavior - like the one I mentioned, a peak in susceptibility at critical temperature, etc.

Comment: @hongchaniyi, try also to compare your results with known one, such as these here http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9904408 (and refs inside)

Comment: Due to the lack of anisotropy, is it not that you can turn the complete magnetization without changing the energy, as long as all relative angles stay the same? What if you calculate the average m relative to the average theta? Note, if you use absolute angles fluctuations around an average theta of 0° do seem less dramatic than the same angular fluctuations around 60°.

Comment: You can make a quick check by fixing e.g. theta[0][0][0]=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous comments are almost ok, your actual problem seems to be that you do not average over the magnetization. You are measuring `<cos(theta)>`, which is the average of `m_x`. So just change

`m = magnetization_cossin();`

to

`magnetization_cossin(&mx, &my);`

where you define

```
void magnetization_cossin(double* mx, double* my)
{
    int x, y, z;
    double m_cos = 0;
    double m_sin = 0;

    for(z = 0; z < Lz; z++)
    for(y = 0; y < Ly; y++)
    for(x = 0; x < Lx; x++)  // sweep lattice fine
    {
        m_cos += cos(theta[x][y][z]);
        m_sin += sin(theta[x][y][z]);
    }
    *mx=m_cos
    *my=m_sin
    return;
}
```

and then calculating `m` as

`m=sqrt(mx*mx+my*my)/N_site`

By the way, for checking the overall behaviour, it is not necessary to calculate energy and magnetization ever step, but every 10 to 50 or so would be enough (to speed things up; put an additional counter that you will reset accordingly ).

Comment: You are right! I made mistakes in calculating the magnetization. Thank you very much to check my whole problem!